# Spring Boot schema.sql - drop db schema on restart

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, database-schema

Hi I'm using Spring Boot version 1.5.9.

When using Spring Boot to initialize `schema.sql` for mysql database, it works all fine and the database schema is getting created successfully. But on restart of the application this `schema.sql` script is executing again and the application fails to start because the tables already exist.

I tried `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` option in `application.properties` but it does not have any effect (probably because it only works for Hibernate entities which I'm not using)

Is there a way to have Spring Boot to re-create schema from `schema.sql` every time on restart if the database is not in-memory one?

GitHub:
https://github.com/itisha/spring-batch-demo/tree/database-input

Comment: can you please show your code

Comment: Have you tryed something like `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-update-`

Comment: @Bhushan Uniyal added link to Github at the bottom of the description
@Zorglube `create-update` seem to be an invalid option, but i tried `update`, didn't help(

Comment: @Bhushan Uniyal there was a github link to the wrong branch, just fixed, sorry

Comment: @ITisha i have go through your code, I think best thing and best practics is you need to use liquibase
it is just like git for your code, Liquibase is an open source database-independent library for tracking, managing and applying database schema changes.
http://www.liquibase.org/

Comment: @Bhushan Uniyal I think you are right. But the way Spring Boot works with schema.sql seem strange to me. It's supposed to create a DB, why does it have to execute it every time then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc) you can simply ignore exceptions by setting `spring.datasource.continue-on-error` property to `true`

> Spring Boot enables the fail-fast feature of the Spring JDBC
>   initializer by default, so if the scripts cause exceptions the
>   application will fail to start. You can tune that using
>   spring.datasource.continue-on-error.

or even turn it off with `spring.datasource.initialize` set to `false`

> You can also disable initialization by setting spring.datasource.initialize to false.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the best option available for my case

Answer (score 3):

A workaround could be, to change the create statements in your schema.sql 
from

```
 CREATE TABLE test .....
```

to

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test ...
```

use the IF NOT EXISTS statements

Answer (score 1):

turn off automatic schema creation to avoid conflicts: add this line in your application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Comment: Unfortunately this option does not have any effect either